# Inject javascript proxy

Tags: proxy

Hie.

I'm working on a JS library that makes changes to dom elements and I would like to be able to show people it's effect in my site.

I'm trying to setup some sort of proxy similar to a transparent proxy that I can call him with the url I want to test and it will inject the JS to the site I'm in.

The idea is opening an iframe to the proxy server with a query parameter of the url we want to test. then the server would pull the data, inject a js file to the page and will return the data. 
As this should run in the client's browser, I can't make them update the proxy setting.

I thought about using Privoxy or similar proxy servers but couldn't find the right config/feature that will allow me to see the updated data in my browser as a regular client would.

I've also used node.js redirect but several sites blocked that access - not sure if it was port forwarding or anything else.

How can I create a dynamic proxy server that I can send the url to and get the site with the injected javascript?

Thanks in advance,
Shahar

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like something that is potentially a "black hat" feature that you would be wanting to add to your local network.

Personally the simplest solution would be to configure a DNS server to route all requests to a single IP address, have that address have a instance of Apache running with a catch-all virtual host and .htaccess rules to pipe all requests through a single php script.

The script that you would then write would then be written to invoke curl to grab the data from the real web server and then you can parse the response and data that you are trying to inject.

Ofcourse you will have to check that you are reading a html file and every page which is served over https would tell the user that the site or connection  is "untrusted" ( and this would pretty much include every single login page from pretty much every popular web service )